# play-services-base 8.1.0 Could not find element /manifest/application

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services

I am trying to package my android project of my libgdx game in which I successfully implemented ads. It works fine when I run it on the device but when I try to package it with the gradle task assembleRelease it throws this:

```
:android:processReleaseManifest
[F:\Java\ElementNinja\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.

Execution failed for task ':android:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

the library play-services-base in the direction above indeed is missing the
application tag and therefore it fails merging the manifests. This library is created upon build and adding in a application tag does not help, as expected. Its recreated when I try to assemble. So I just checked and play-services-base is the only library that misses the application tag. Its only missing in the version 8.1.0 though. 
7.8.0 has the tag.

when I try to compile it with version 7.8.0 it throws:

```
[F:\Java\ElementNinja\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-location\7.8.0\AndroidManifest.xml:1, 
C:\Users\Silvio\AppData\Local\Temp\manifestMerge7855374264263370310.xml:7] Main manifest has <uses-feature android:glEsVersion='0x00010000'> but library uses glEsVersion='0x00020000'
Note: main manifest lacks a <uses-feature android:glEsVersion> declaration, and thus defaults to glEsVersion=0x00010000.
```

I don't know what to do with that either :D

All my other libs/plugins are up to date and I am using Eclipse 4.6.

In my build.gradle file I call:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:+"
```

'Refresh All' with gradle throws no errors. As I said its working when installed from Eclipse. The ads are working fine in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after another day of trying and failing miserably I decided to start from scratch. I created a fresh libgdx project and copied my source code into it. First try, it compiled successfully. Cannot describe the feeling, haha.

I have to admit, the libgdx project itself(not the version. it was up to date) was created over 1 year ago. When I roughly compared build.gradle files and other stuff of the projects I saw some differences.

I guess some old gradle tool versions were used in the old project and therefore it wanted that application tag although its not in all the newer versions of the google play service libs. I'm having problems with googles libs since I started. this was my first success.